# How to use the content of a string variable to access an inner resource of a Resources.resx in C#?

Tags: c#

In Resources.resx, when accessing a resource in C# visual studio, you do it by : "Properties.Resources." and then a list of resources is avaulable for selection.
I am trying to access resources without knowing the resource name in advanced, its name is revealed on run time only from a content of some string.

Is there any direct way to access the Resources.resx resources names or it can only be done by collecting all resources to a dictionary or some thing like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load the resource string manually using code similar to the below:

```
Assembly resourceAssembly = Assembly.Load("<AppName>.Resources");
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("<AppName>.Resources.<ResourceName>", resourceAssembly);

string resource = resourceManager.GetString("<ResourceName>", culture));
```